# how to do force deploy maven project via jenkins..?

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment

when I do deploy of `maven` project via `jenkins` the output says success but i cant see changes on the server. what i can see is the target folder on the `jenkins` server contain all the required changes but dont know why it is unable to deploy those files on the test server, below are some details.

**command to deploy**

```
clean package jboss-as:deploy -DjbossUser=${jbossUser} -DjbossPass=${jbossPass} -DjbossServer=${jbossServer} -DjbossServerPort=${jbossServerPort}
```

file type that contain the changes : *.html & *.js

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: Maven deploy is not intended to deployment on real servers. better deploy artifacts into repositoy manager and make a separate go to deploy the artifact to your application server...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue. It seems there are some deploy mechanism exists in Jenkins where the version is configured. It should take the build(snapshot) version from pom.xml